# The nearest row in the other table

Tags: sql, nearest-neighbor

One table is a sample of users and their purchases.

```
Structure:

Email | NAME | TRAN_DATETIME (Varchar)
```

So we have customer email + FirstName&LastName + Date of transaction

and the second table that comes from second system contains all users, they sensitive data and when they got registered in our system.

```
Simplified Structure:

Email | InstertDate (varchar)
```

My task is to count minutes difference between the rows insterted from sale(first table)and the rows with users and their sensitive data.
The issue is that second table contain many rows and I want to find the nearest in time row that was inserted in 2nd table, because sometimes it may be a few minutes difeerence(delay or opposite of delay)and sometimes it can be a few days.

So for x email I have row in 1st table:

```
E_MAIL          NAME        TRAN_DATETIME
p****@****.eu   xxx xxx     2021-10-04 00:03:09.0000000
```

But then I have 3 rows and the lastest is the one I want to count difference

```
Email           InstertDate
p****@****.eu   2021-05-20 19:12:07
p****@****.eu   2021-05-20 19:18:48
p****@****.eu   2021-10-03 18:32:30  <--
```

I wrote that some query, but I have no idea how to match nearest row in the 2nd table

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) 
          ,a.[E_MAIL]
          ,a.[NAME]
          ,a.[TRAN_DATETIME]
          ,CASE WHEN b.EMAIL IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS 'EXISTS'
          ,(ABS(CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(Datetime,LEFT(a.[TRAN_DATETIME],10),120))) - CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(Datetime,LEFT(b.[INSERTDATE],10),120)))  as 'DateAccuracy'
          
      FROM [crm].[SalesSampleTable] a 
      left join [crm].[SensitiveTable] b on a.[E_MAIL]) = b.[EMAIL]
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest you store the date/time information using a `TIMESTAMP` data type, not `VARCHAR`.

Comment: What's the database? Looks like Sybase or SQL Server.

Comment: If you store the dates as strings instead of native date datatypes, then *you* have to write more code: code that has already been written, debugged, and tested continually by the RDBMS vendor. At a minimum, you'd have to execute code to convert strings to dates for every instances of a string that needs to be inspected. Massively wasteful code.

Comment: Verify the requirement: "count minutes difference between the rows inserted from sale(first table)and the rows with users and their sensitive data."  since it's a M:M Relationship you'd have multiple results for each user.  You're comment of "I want to find the nearest in time row that was inserted in 2nd table" means you're picking a different entry for the same email for different sales... I can't imagine a business case for this.  So please explain either why you have multiple records for the same user in a user table, or why you're not just taking the most "Current" user timestamp..

Comment: It's SSMS database

Comment: @xQbert - the business case is to count latency between two systems and their write ability, because we want to transform our systems into more near-realtime processig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally untested: I'd need sample data and database  the area of suspect is the casting of dates and the datemath.... since I dont' know what RDBMS and version this is.. consider the following "pseudo code".

We assign a row number to the absolute difference in seconds between the dates those with rowID of 1 win.

```
WTIH CTE AS (
SELECT A.*, B.* row_number() over (PARTITION BY A.e_mail
                                   ORDER BY abs(datediff(second, cast(Tran_dateTime as Datetime), cast(InsterDate as DateTime)) desc) RN
FROM [crm].[SalesSampleTable] a 
LEFT JOIN [crm].[SensitiveTable] b
     on a.[E_MAIL] = b.[EMAIL])
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Note: This is a solution in the vein of doing something.... It may not be performant/optimal.  The next step is to do it right and then make it better...